# Build android application for release using ant in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

When signing and building my application for release through ant in eclipse I am getting an error.

I am using the ant task that comes with the android sdk.

Keystore file, alias, pass are defined in ant.properties.

> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:981: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:995: Execute
>   failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jarsigner.exe" (in
>   directory "C:\dev\projects\sample1"): CreateProcess error=2, The
>   system cannot find the file specified

Followed instructions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the folder YOUR_JDK\bin in your path

(YOUR_JDK being the folder where you have installed the Java JDK)

Comment: and then after that restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for the Jar signer in the wrong location.

Might be worth checking your [path environment variable is set up correctly](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) (so that it can find jarsigner.exe)